# Using Patator ssh_login module how can I get the output to show only on success

Tags: brute-force, kali-linux

I have the following command:

```
patator ssh_login host=<ip> port=<port> user=<user> password=FILE0 0=<path to pwdlist>
```

I would like to output the success result only and not output every attempt. Is this possible?

My first attempt was:

```
patator ssh_login host=<ip> port=<port> user=<user> password=FILE0 0=<path to pwdlist> | grep "INFO - 0"
```

but that didn't work.

Can anyone assist.

Comment: the additional switch `-x ignore:mesg='Authentication failed'`, as listed in the _patator_ help, does not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're tied to `patator`? It looked like the `--allow-ignore-failures` may help but I just ran it and it didn't suppress failed attempts. **I would use `hydra`** as it's a lot simpler. This should work for you:

```
hydra -l <user> -P <password-list-file> ssh://target
```

(Hydra was quick answer -- hopefully I can play around with `patator` later and give an answer for that too...)

Comment: I am using hydra more often as I agree with you on its simplicity. Just trying to get my hands dirty on other tools as well. Appreciate the command.

Answer (score 0):

I agree patator needs some time to get used to.
Here's the option you're (or were) looking for :

`-x ignore:code=1`

And if you want to use the fgrep or egrep filter module included in patator :

`-x ignore:egrep="Authentication failed."` should do the trick.
Or any regex you want.

And also, by default patator doesn't filter the equivalent of stderr (the error data stream), so sometimes you can miss filters you put in the pipe, an option allows you to include stderr in the filters pipe (as mentionned @deletedhead) :
`--allow-ignore-failures`

Enjoy